# Как в PHP сделать шаг назад при этом не теряя прежде введенные данные?

Tags: php

Вот у меня код:

```
echo "<center><a href='login.php'><img src='img/error.png' /></a><center>";
```

Т.е при ошибке выскакивает фотка. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на фотку, пользователь вернулся обратно и исправил свою ошибку. Но при этом чтобы не терялись ранее им введенные данные.

**UPDATE**

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на фотку выполнялась функция?

Comment: Раз Вы эти данные проверили, значит они у Вас на сервере есть. Вы сами формируете html для пользователя, возьмите и пропишите их в нужных местах.

Comment: создавайте новый вопрос, вместо update, а еще лучще выучите азы php.

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняйте промежуточные некорректные данные на сервере, а при клике на фотке сделайте GET-параметр какой-нибудь (например: ?notcorrect). Далее проверяйте этот параметр на существование, и если он существует - подгружайте эти промежуточные данные в HTML форму. Но это костыли, на JS это делается в разы проще и быстрее.